# In Oracle SQL split and concat to make IP address

Tags: oracle, plsql

Oracle SQL (PLSQL)
I am writing a trigger that when a column on table_a.ID is updated, table_b.IP will updated with an IP address that consists of the ID (4 digit number) split where the first 2 digits are in the second octet and the last 2 digits are in the third octet.

The IP address always starts: 10.1
and the IP address always ends with 68

I know how to concat the string but I do not know how to split and concat in the same declaration

```
Example:
| ID |
------
|0999|
```

IP address should be 10.109.99.68

```
Example:
| ID |
------
|6666|
```

IP address should be 10.166.66.68

...and so forth.

```
DECLARE
   IP_1 VARCHAR2(15) :=
```

Comment: This look like a very "special" design. For sure it is not future proof at all and error prone. For example, number `2222` could be IP `10.122.22.68` or `10.12.222.68`. Number `1111` could be IP `10.111.11.68` or `10.11.111.68` or `10.11.11.168` or `10.111.1.168`  or `10.1.111.168`

Comment: It is extremely specialized.  Currently, we use a shell script in bash to calculate the IP address of a node in our network to create our hosts file each time we bring a new node online.
Our nodes are broken down by subdivisions and the ip addresses are already set by this ip scheme for abou 3200 nodes - each natted on our network.
I am putting in a trigger to populate a table with the IP addresses so we can use that table to create the hosts file automagically.  This will allow the hosts file to be maintained with real data and allow us to eliminate a time-wasting step.

Comment: Still, I would recommend to store the actual IP-Address. It is just a few bytes more and maintenance will be simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may cast the integer `ID` to text, then use a concatenation:

```sql
SELECT '10.' || SUBSTR(LPAD(TO_CHAR(ID), 4, '0'), 1, 2) || '.' ||
                SUBSTR(LPAD(TO_CHAR(ID), 4, '0'), 3, 2) || '.68' AS ip
FROM yourTable;
```

Note carefully that I first cast the `ID` to text, then left pad with zeroes to a length of 4.  This padding is necessary because integers do not actually have any leading zeroes.

### Demo

Comment: This is perfect, I was able to do:

IP_REG_1_IP VARCHAR2(20) := '10.1' || SUBSTR(LPAD(TO_CHAR(:new.POS_STORE), 4, '0'), 1, 2) || '.' || SUBSTR(LPAD(TO_CHAR(:new.POS_STORE), 4, '0'), 3, 2) || '.68';


to suit my coding needs.  I hope one day to be as knowledgable so as to impart knowledge to others.

Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

You may use [number formatting](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-096CA64F-1DA3-4C49-A18B-ECC7518EE56C) to convert a number to character string:

- Use `0` as a required position, which will be filled with the digit on that position if it exists or zero if not.
- Use `.` (dot) as a group separator and `G` as a placeholder for group separator.
- Use string concatenation to build the result.

Note: `trim` is required because the first position is filled with a blank (space) - an absent sign for non-negative number.

```
select
  column_value,
  '10.1' || trim(to_char(column_value, '00G00', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='' .''')) || '.68' as ip
from sys.odcinumberlist(
  12,
  123,
  1234,
  99,
  909,
  6666,
  6660
)
```

| COLUMN_VALUE | IP |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 10.100.12.68 |
| 123 | 10.101.23.68 |
| 1234 | 10.112.34.68 |
| 99 | 10.100.99.68 |
| 909 | 10.109.09.68 |
| 6666 | 10.166.66.68 |
| 6660 | 10.166.60.68 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cHybbh19)

Comment: If you use the `FM` fill-mode modifier then you don't need to trim - [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fbWRvg_f).

Comment: @AlexPoole Nice point, thanks a lot! I've forgotten that it's valid for both datetime and number format models.